# How to read assembly information, say Vendor using batch script or vbscript?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

We have around 200-300 assemblies and exe's which includes 3rd party assemblies in Binrel folder and we have to digitally sign these assemblies and exe's that are in BinRel folder which are not following any naming pattern. We are restricted not to use post build event of the CSproj files.
So we need a script either in batch or VB which reads the assembly Vendor and basing on the vendor, we are expecting to digitally sign the files. Is that possible to read the vendor information of a dll????

Answer (score 2):

Change `root_dir`  to the folder you want to examine.

```
@echo off

set "root_dir=C:\some_bins"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%# in ("%root_dir%\*") do (
    set "file_path=%%~f#"

    set "file_path_q=!file_path:\=\\!"
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('"WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name='!file_path_q!' get  Manufacturer  /format:Textvaluelist"') do (

        for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%M in ("%%f") do (
            echo !file_path! vendor : %%M
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

*note*: This uses the same source that npocmaka uses in its answer (faster than me this time), but the retrieval process is different

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Where to get the files
    set "binFolder=c:\windows"

    rem Retrieve input folder elements that we will use in the query
    for %%a in ("%binFolder%\") do (set "binPath=%%~pa" & set "binDrive=%%~da")

    rem Retrieve the required data from the source files
    for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a in ('
        wmic datafile where ( 
            drive^="%binDrive%" 
            and path^="%binPath:\=\\%" 
            and extension^="dll" 
        ^) get caption^, manufacturer^, Version /format:csv
    ') do (

        echo [%%a][%%b]

    )
```

It just asks wmi for the required information, indicating exactly from where to retrieve it.

The resulting list will have a empty line, a header line (from here the `skip=2`) and the records with data. Records include the computer name (automatically included when asking for information in csv format), the full path to the file, the manufacturer, and the version, with commas as delimiters that are used to split the record an retrieve the needed fields.

The version field is included to avoid a problem with `wmic` output data that includes an aditional carriage return at the end of each line.

Comment: Nice example how to escape the wmic expression